# apt-get suppress warning about missing repo

Tags: linux, apt

There is a development and production environment. In each one there is a Debian repository. For example `http://dev` and `http://prod`.

When the machine is transfered (physically) to the production environment, how to avoid changing `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

One solution is to write both:

```
deb http://dev/debian main
deb http://prod/debian main
```

It's ok to have a warning about inaccessible `http://prod/` in the dev environment. But how to get rid of the warning in the production network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat mirror feature. In `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb mirror://localhost/mirrors.txt jessie main
```

And in `mirrors.txt` hosted on the same machine:

```
http://dev/debian
http://prod/debian
```

So, it'll find some repository in every config.

But it complains anyways. I'll go with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generates a list of available repositories.

set -e

release_codename="$(lsb_release -cs)"

all_mirrors_list=/etc/locate-my-repositories/all-my-mirrors.list
active_list=/var/lib/locate-my-repositories/my.list

mirrors="$(cat "$all_mirrors_list")"

active=$(for r in $mirrors; do
    if curl -s "$r"/dists/"$release_codename"/main/binary-"$(dpkg --print-architecture)"/Release | grep -q '^Component:'; then
        printf '%s\n' "$r"
    fi
done)

# Formats a valid /etc/apr/sources.list: makes "deb http://url jessie main"
# entry from "http://url".
function to_sources_list() {
    sed "s/\(.*\)/deb \\1 $release_codename main/"
}

if [ -z "$active" ]; then
    # Nothing is found. Give everything to apt-get, maybe it will be more lucky.
    cat "$all_mirrors_list"
else
    printf '%s\n' "$active"
fi | to_sources_list > "$active_list"
```